# Blank page after deployment on app dev Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, deployment

Got a problem after deploying my symfony2 app to staging server. I don't get any errors but a white blank page, even on app_dev.php. I even tried to deploy a different app to the server which is working, so there shouldn't be a problem with the server but with my application.

I already did:
 - app/console cache:clear --no-debug --env=prod
 - deleting/recreate app/cache & app/logs (also permissions 777 are defined)
 - I also took a look at common error locations (e.g. app_dev.php/app.php/app_kernel.php/config.yml/parameters.yml) but there is nothing wrong

What else can I do? I have experienced this before but in that case app/cache & app/logs was the root of my problems, unfortunately not this time...

Comment: Have you checked logs? @RoyRobsen

Comment: You should check all available logs (symfony logs, apache/nginx.. logs ....). There has to be some logs, if not, check your logs config, maybe you disabled logs under critical level or something similar

Comment: Checked Apache error.log = nothing special, checked Symfony2 Logs are empty. Where do I find nGinx Logs? I do not have a /var/log/nginx directory..

Comment: Do you see apache2 access logs?

Comment: Yes, access.log is existing in /var/logs/apache2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

1. Sticking a test PHP page in the web dir and see if you can hit that file in your browser.
2. Enabling display_errors in php.
3. Check web/config.php to see if you are missing any config settings.

Comment: Done, I got the following error: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required ...web/bootstrap.php.cache! Seems there are some files missing. I will check this out! Thanks!

Comment: It's really weird that this error hasn't shown up in apache errors

Answer (score -2):

Please check your permissions, if you are not sure change them to `chmod -R 777 YOURPROJECT_FOLDER`

Comment: I did it, but nothing happened! Althrough, my other app is working in the same directory. If this was a permission problem, there would be a blank page too, wouldn't?

Comment: If it didn't solve the issue, what do you see in /var/log/nginx-error.log ?

Comment: I solved the issue now! I simply forgot to run composer to install the dependencies.. Also, like I said I do not have "/var/log/nginx-error.log"